# The spin animation set on the image is not working in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to spin an Image it is basically to show that a coin is flipped ( coin Tossing animation ) I have applied this basic animation to the image but it is not getting  animated,

The image is stationary while I tested it on emulator

this is my index.android.js file :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  View,
  Animated,
  Easing
} from 'react-native';

export default class animateTest extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.spinValue = new Animated.Value(0);
    }

    spin() {
      this.spinValue.setValue(0);
      Animated.timing(
        this.spinValue, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 1500,
          useNativeDriver: true,
          easing: Easing.linear
        }
      ).start();
    }

  render() {
    const spin = this.spinValue.interpolate({
inputRange: [0, 1],
outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg']
});

    return (
      <View style={styles.ViewStyle}>
      <Animated.Image
            style={[
              styles.coinStyle,
               {
                transform: [
                  { rotate: spin }
                ]
              }
            ]}
             source={require('./Images/Coin_Tail.png')}
            style={styles.coinStyle} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = {
  coinStyle: {
    width: 150,
height: 150,
  },
  ViewStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
   alignItems: 'center',
   backgroundColor: 'black'
  }
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent('animateTest', () => animateTest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code have 2 issues:

1) In your `render` function, you have a duplicated `style` prop for your image that override the first style with transform styling. To fix it, remove the second style prop

2) Your code did not trigger the spin animation, you can add a touchable with on press event to call your `spin` method. For quick test, you can add

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.spin();
  }
```

Comment: Thankyou so much alpha it works well now 
how can i make it vertical just like the way of tossing a coin

Comment: can u tell me how to make it as a vertical rotation  @alpha

Comment: instead of transform `rotate`, change it to `rotateX`